# Eigenvalues of an operator in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, isometry

This is from Cheney's Analysis for Applied Mathematics:

*Let $X$ be a Hilbert space having a countable orthonormal base $\{u_1, u_2, \dots\}$. Define an operator $A$ by the equation
$$Ax = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x, u_n \rangle u_{n+1}$$
What are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Is $A$ compact?

Is $A$ Hermitian?

What is the norm of $A$?*

Here are my thoughts on this:
From the orthonormal basis theorem, for each $x$ in the Hilbert space $X$, we have $x =\sum \langle x,u_i \rangle u_i$. Let $a_i :=\langle x,u_i\rangle$. Then $Ax = \sum a_n u_{n+1}.$ Solving for eigenvalues, $Ax = \lambda x$, yields $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n u_{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda a_n u_n.$$ But I cannot go further from here to find the eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues. This is specifically difficult to intuitively imagine, as each component of $x$  in the $n$-th direction is projected by $A$ to the $(n+1)$-th one.

Am I on the right track so far? I'd appreciate any help on this part and the rest of the problem (whether $A$ is compact and Hermitian).

Comment: The map is $Lx = (0,x_1,x_2,...)$. Write $Lx=\lambda x$. Solve for $x$.

Comment: Thanks, but this will lead to $\lambda x_1=0$, $\lambda x_2=x_1$,..., $\lambda x_{n+1} =x_n$, which results in the trivial $x=0.$ Is this the right conclusion?!

Comment: Yes, the right shift has no eigenvalues. Sorry, I should have used $L$, I confuse my right & left :-).

Comment: Thanks so much. So exactly because it is a shift, its norm is 1. And it cannot be compact. I wish you had written your answer so I could accept it for future references and other users. Thanks any way :D

Comment: You may look it up [here without leaving math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043965/eigenvalue-of-a-unilateral-shift-operator) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising answer, to avoid the question dangling in the unanswered queue, made community:

- *$A$ has no eigenvalue.*
  $A$'s spectrum is the closed unit disk: $\,\sigma(A)=\big\{\lambda\in\mathbb C\,\big\vert\, |\lambda|\leqslant 1\big\}$
- *$A$ is the Right shift operator, thus an isometry, and in particular non-compact.*
- *Its adjoint $A^*$ is a partial isometry, so $A$ is not Hermitian.*
- $\|A\|=1\,$ *follows from the preceding.*

This subject is well represented on this site$-$do a search in the header line, by looking up "shift operator spectrum" for instance.